# Canvas drawImage() not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This Javascript code draw part of the image on the canvas:

```
var img = document.getElementById('img');
var canvas = document.getElementById('can');
//canvas.width = img.width;
//canvas.height = img.height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
```

But when I uncomment the middle lines to set the canvas width and height, the drawImage() does not work.
What should I check in order to find the problem?

Comment: Why do you think that uncommenting produced the problem?

Answer (score 16):

You need to **wait for the browser to load the image**.

Use `onload` event if image was not yet loaded and change your code to something like this:

```
var img = document.getElementById('img');
var canvas = document.getElementById('can');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var callback = function(image) {
   if(!image) image = this;
   canvas.width = img.width;
   canvas.height = img.height;
   ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
}

if(img.complete) { //check if image was already loaded by the browser
   callback(img);
}else {
   img.onload = callback;
}
```

**[See this working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mf4SW/)**

Comment: will this work if image was already loaded before binding onload

Comment: @sabithpocker i updated my answer to check is it was already loaded. now it works on both cases.

Comment: I already called the code from img.onload = function() { ... }

Comment: @Joe what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that the problem happens inside the callback

Comment: @Joe See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mf4SW/. Use the same login and tell me how it worked. Also don't forget this check: `if(!image) image = this;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = document.getElementById('img');
```

Try naming the variable something else. Also make sure some image is loaded.

Try my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aliasm2k/tAum2/ for more ideas

Answer (score 0):

The width and height image attributes aren't set until the image is loaded, so i propose you to put your code in onLoad() image event.